# Looping through dynamically created controls

Tags: vb.net, loops, button, runtime

I have a number of dynamically created buttons (buttons generated at run time), and also a number of dynamically created panels. I want to do something similar to the code below although i know that this code will not work.

```
For i = 1 to NumberOfButtons
    button(i).top = panel(i).top
next
```

The buttons are named button1, button2 etc. And the panels are also named panel1, panel2 etc.
This is all being written in VB Express 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you generate your buttons and panels, you need to store them into an array. Then you can access it via index like your have in your code sample. Another option would be to do it via `Me.Controls("button1")` and similar, but I would consider this bad coding.

Comment: Im going to give an attempt at using an array, but at least theres another option. Thanks

Comment: @user2179046: You can't go wrong with an array. String consts for names are fragile, for long term maintainability.

Comment: Just an update, got it all completely working and learnt a lot more about arrays in the process! I tried it using the me.controls("button1") way first. Then tried using an array instead and the code became so much more simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
For i As Integer = 1 To theTopNumber
  Me.Controls("button" & i.ToString).Top = Me.Controls("panel" & i.ToString).Top
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Would't this work?

```
For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls
    For Each pnl In Me.Controls
        btn.Top = pnl.Top
     Next
Next
```

Please (if you are satisfied) up vote or mark as answer  since my mysteriously got banned for no particular reason. It might help to re-enable it :/

;)